# Python Tkinter window mysteriously not opening

Tags: python, tkinter

The following simple Python program fails for me for some reason:

```
from tkinter import *
print("Submit the following form:")
a = str(input("Have you registered before? (y/n) "))
if a == 'y':
    root = Tk()
else:
    # Code path for unregistered users, not relevant to the question.
    pass
```

Typing `y` when the program is running does nothing, the Tkinter window never opens.

Comment: Entering this in my interactive Python 3 interpreter on Windows works just fine. Are you running the code in an interactive prompt, IDLE or are you just doubleclicking the script from its folder? If the latter is the case, you need to add some sort of event loop after creating the window, otherwise it just pops in and instantly dies because the program ends on that and the interpreter shuts down.

Comment: I tried adding root.mainloop() in the code but the tkinter window still doesnt show

Answer (score 1):

You forget to add `root.mainloop()` in your code.
Try This:

```
from tkinter import *
print("Submit The Form")
a=str(input("Have You Registered Before?(y/n)"))
if a=='y':
    root=Tk()
    #your code
    root.mainloop()
else:
    pass
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I tried it out with the change that you specified and it still isn't opening the tkinter window

Comment: No it doesn't... Actually I tried the same code on notepad and it worked. Can that happen?? Can't I do something so that it will work in python?

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of python installed??And also what is the name of your file you using in python??

Comment: No i just have one version installed...... If by name of file you mean the name with which i saved the code its python_project.py

Comment: Then you have not problem in code as it's working for me on my computer.

Comment: which version of python are you executing this code on